# HTML5 Boilerplate, X-UA-Compatible and Windows Phone 7

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, html5boilerplate

i am having an issue with most of my new sites which use H5BP when viewed from Windows Phone 7 (or 7.5). The problem is that this HTML tag in the site's source

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

which should actually support different mobile devices, prevents the user of a mobile device (in our case Windows Phone 7 or greater user) to zoom in on the text (and the site itself).

Using this tag the mobile browser will adjust the size of the site according to the mobile viewport (i.e. mobile screen width and height). However, the problem is, when the user tries to zoom in on the text using the zoom-in gesture, the zooming doesn't work. It tries to zoom in but quickly returns to the initial width.

Has anyone else noticed this problem and if so, what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to test adding `user-scalable=yes` to see how Windows Phone handles the tag.

Although the tag is supported by almost all mobile browsers it isn't a standard tag (originated on the iPhone) so the implementation may differ. I find that Safari has the best documentation on the tag and as such I sourced it below.

This tag should be worth testing:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

Source: [Safari Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

Additional resource: [IE Mobile Viewport via Windows Phone Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/22/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7.aspx).

Comment: I don't have an option to check it out right now since I had to send my phone to service. But this looks like it could help. Though I see that the 'yes' value is the default so one would expect it to work without explicitly setting it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a windows phone to test but perhaps adding the user-scalable=yes may help on windows mobile.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```